# I have installed nodejs on windows how should i use it in WSL?

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having problem using libraries installed on windows to WSL and vice versa. I don't want to install not just nodejs but other things twice just to use it in WSL and also in normal text editors like VS code, atom, etc.

Comment: As far as I know, WSL and the actual windows does not share the same environment variable. Its probably solvable if you're a linux expert, but the easiest way would be to jsut install node inside the WSL. It won't be "multiple" times, just twice :)

Comment: I would not install them twice. I would use a shared space for WSL and your Windows machine(e.g. `/mnt/c/Your/Path/On/Your/Drive`) and use your existing VSCode, atom etc. for editing and access the things where you need WSL in WSL. With this you will not even need a X-Server for the text-editors.

Comment: Also, you can switch between WSL and cmd by typing `wsl -- <command>` and `cmd.exe /C <command>` or just `wsl` or `cmd.exe`

Comment: @dan1st by shared space do you mean  just install anything on wsl? And use it by /mnt/c/....? But installing other things like kotlin on wsl is really daunting task.

Comment: @Gibor Not just nodejs but other things too. some times It becomes really hard to download some things on WSL that's why. I was unable to install kotlin on WSL. i'm use WSL as a default terminal of vscode.

Comment: @NikhilShisode no, I mean, that you use your existing installation.

Comment: That's what I want to do but don't know how. Do i need to add path? What is shared space?

Comment: You can access your C: drive from WSL. It is located under `/mnt/c`. This is what I mean with sharded space. The path that WSL uses is the Linux Path and a the Windows Path by default. Also, WSL supports Windows binaries. So, you can execute both Windows and Linux applications from wsl. For example you can execute cmd from wsl by just typing `cmd.exe` or `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe`. You can also access a Linux Application (e.g. find) from cmd by e.g. typing `wsl -- find`.

Comment: Literally things on WSL belong to another virtual machine, not your host Windows environment. So, wasting time here won’t save you any disk space.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install NodeJS from the NodeJS repositories inside of WSL in order to use npm and Node within WSL.

Node and other things that are not working in WSL have to installed in Linux way because windows packages are not compatible in WSL as it is based on Linux OS you have to install them in WSL in order to use them there.

node.exe is NodeJS from your Windows environment - that's for Windows, not WSL.

You need to install NodeJS from the NodeJS repositories inside of WSL in order to use npm and Node within WSL. DO NOT rely on the Windows solutions for installing WSL.

[Microsoft has specific documentation on how to do this, provided you're using WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl)

Answer (score -1):

The complete instruction can be found here [set-up-on-wsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-wsl2)

If you are too busy to follow the link, follow these steps in the WSL:

1. Use curl to install nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

2. For installing NodeJs (lts)

```
nvm install node --lts
```

3. You can also install specific node version. Check all commands uses by typing `nvm` in your terminal.
4. Done Node has been successfully installed in your WSL,  `nvm ls` will list all the installations.

You can use the Node installed in your WSL for developing. Point to your working directory and use `code .` to open VSCode. Also, if you want to access your windows directories you can mount them by using `/mnt/<dir>`

*If you face any issues during installation it is better to use the link I have provided above.*

Also note that, the Node installed in the WSL can only be used, iff your working directory is in the WSL or is linked with your WSL(by using `mnt`).